# Bind ng-model dynamically with data from ng-repeat (Angular 1.5.7)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

****EDIT: PROBLEM SOLVED! Neuronet's solution was the answer:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in $ctrl.posts">
<textarea class="postBox"  ng-model="$ctrl.comment.content" name="content" /></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="$ctrl.postCommentSubmit(post.id)" />
</div>
```

Below is my original post:

I've spent the past 3 hours on this problem. I have an array of posts that I have passed from my controller to my template under the name "posts". Each post in posts is an array holding various key-value pairs such as "id" (value being an integer), "content" (value being a string), etc. I want to include a form to send a PostComment post to my api. The PostComment post requires that I send it a foreign key (representing the related post) and a content field. I wish to get the foreign key dynamically from ng-repeat .

My template looks like this:

```
            <div ng-repeat="post in $ctrl.posts">
              ....
              <form ng-submit="$ctrl.postCommentSubmit()">

                <input class="hidden" type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.postCommentArray.postForeignKey" value="{{ post.id }}" name="postid"  /> 
                <textarea class="postBox"  ng-model="$ctrl.postCommentArray.content" name="content" /></textarea>
                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />

              </form>

            </div>
```

The pertinent part of my controller looks like this:

```
self.postCommentArray = {
        content: '',
        postForeignKey:  '',
      };
```

I am attempting to get the foreign key from post.id (the "post" is from post in $ctrl.posts in ng-repeat). I cannot seem to figure out a way to do this. I have tried both value="{{ post.id }}" and ng-value="{{ post.id }}" but for various reasons neither works. Ng-value only works on radio, but I cannot automatically check the option, and value does not work together with ng-model since they are both competing to set the value.

I'd be much obliged to anyone who could help me.

Comment: Could you give an example of what $ctrl.posts looks like?

Comment: Sure here is an example with 2 items listed in the array. 

[

    {
        "post_comments": [ ],
        "user": .....,
        "timestamp": "2016-07-01T18:31:36.413319Z",
        "content": "this is new post",
        "post_likes": [ ],
        "id": 20
    },
    {
        "post_comments": [ ],
        "user": .....,
        "timestamp": "2016-07-01T18:40:02.406049Z",
        "content": "this is another post",
        "post_likes": [ ],
        "id": 21
    },
]

Comment: @lostcoder12345 if there is an answer you deem to be correct, pls click on the check (tick) box next to it.

Comment: Thank you for informing me. I have done so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using the CommentArray ? just use comment as your model
You can pass a post id in postCommentSubmit

```js
<div ng-repeat="post in $ctrl.posts">
<textarea class="postBox"  ng-model="post.comment.content" name="content" /></textarea>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="$ctrl.postCommentSubmit(post.id)" />
</div>
```

Comment: "You can pass a post id in postCommentSubmit" - That sounds smart. Let me give that a try. Thanks! I'll be back at my computer in about 3 hours and let you know if that worked.

Comment: Wow, that worked! THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!


I have to run now but I believe that solved my problem. I'm surprised though because I did not think it would work by merely doing ng-click="$ctrl.postCommentSubmit(post.id)" as you said as opposed to ng-click="$ctrl.postCommentSubmit({{post.id}})"

I tried it the latter way first, and it didn't work. I was about to comment telling you that it didn't work, and that I had to change post.id to {{post.id}} since I was getting that from the ng-repeat. But prior to writing my comment I decided to try your way first, and viola! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest in your controller make your `postCommentSubmit` function look something like this:

```
    $ctrl.postCommentSubmit = function (post, foreign_id) {
        $http.post('/api', {
            "post_comments": post["post_comments"],
            "user": post["user"],
            "timestamp": post["timestamp"],
            "updated": post["updated"],
            "content": post["content"],
            "post_likes": post["post_likes"],
            "id": post["id"],

            "foreign_id": foreign_id
        })
    }
```

And then in your html ng-submit:

```
<form ng-submit="$ctrl.postCommentSubmit(post, $ctrl.postCommentArray.postForeignKey)">
```

Comment: I'm not posting to the "Post" model. I'm posting to the "PostComment" model, which takes a Post ID as a foreignkey. 

The api endpoint for my post comment expects data that looks like this - 

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"content":"This is a post comment", "post":"20"}' 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post_comments/create/'

I am trying to get post id (which is a foreignkey) from post in $ctrl.posts.